# Trying to make a 'cut' button pairing

Tags: css

I need to make two buttons that are grouped and look similar to this..

```
     ------------------
     |        /       |
     |  btn  /   btn  |
     |      /         |
     ------------------
```

Except I'm completely stuck and have no idea how to do this even on a theoretical level.

Here's my codepen I'm working on http://codepen.io/robguy21/pen/ONEzpb

I don't know how much help that will be though

Comment: Unless you have a Sass->CSS compilation issue, do not use the Sass tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit: you are right this is a better option: http://codepen.io/radvic/pen/aNKKMJ

```
%btn-reset {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: normal;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: auto; 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;

    &:active,
    &:focus { outline:none;}
}

$btnHeight: 45px;

button {
  @extend %btn-reset;
}

.btn-group {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: $btnHeight;
  overflow:hidden;
}

%btn-cont {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn-cont--one {
  @extend %btn-cont;
  background-color: red;
  left: 0;
}

.btn-cont--two {
  @extend %btn-cont;
  background-color: green;
  left: 50%;
}

%btn {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200%;
  left: -50%;
  top: -50%;
  z-index: 5;
  height: 200%;
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
  display: block;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  &:hover {
    background-color: red;
  }
}

.one {
  @extend %btn;
  background-color: #78a44b;
  z-index: 10;
  margin-left:-18%;
  text-indent:18%;
}

.two {
  @extend %btn;
  background-color: #84caab;
  z-index: 5;
  margin-left:18%;
  text-indent:-18%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

button > span{
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(60deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

I'll leave the original link for reference.

original try:
*ok this is probably not the most elegant way of doing it as specially as it involves a negative z-index but here it goes:*
http://codepen.io/radvic/pen/yOEvNw

Comment: So this got me close, but the problem is that the hover gets triggered everywhere in the border area which isn't very user-friendly.

Comment: wow, awesome I was honestly starting to believe it was just out of reach O_o. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, i am create a JSFIDDLE for you

```
.second{
    border-bottom: 100px solid red;
    border-left: 60px solid transparent;
    border-right: 0px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 100px;
    float:right;
    margin-top:-100px;
}
.first{
    border-top: 100px solid green;
    border-left: 0px solid transparent;
    border-right:60px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 100px;
    float:left;
}
```

Just check it out this link [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/aj_gupta/7skjfqx0/)